# Push Notification data

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project that need to send a push notification to an android device where my app is installed. I already done this by following the quick-start tutorial by Firebase and got successfully received the notification on my Android device.

Question: How can you access the notification data, if you have clicked on the app icon instead of the push notification?

Answer (score 1):

when you receive you push message inside your app stored in shared preference with proper key like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("recent_notification_key", "your_notification_data");
editor.commit();
```

Now when you click on your app, inside onCreate of your first activity write following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String notificationString = sharedPref.getString("recent_notification_key", defaultValue);

if (notificationString !=null && !notificationString.equals("")){
\\ you received new notification
}
```